# SQL Server FOR XML coming out in hex / ascii-binary

Tags: sql-server, xml, binary, hex

I am trying to get the XML Schema for a table from our SQL Server database.

If I write this in a SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT * 
FROM trNLSConsignment 
FOR XML AUTO
```

It outputs XML in the result, which starts something like:

```
<trNLSConsignment NLSConsignmentId="1" NoiNLSAnimalTypeId="2" AgeFrom="12"
```

With a column header of:

```
XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
```

Similarly if I want the actual schema and do:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * 
FROM trNLSConsignment 
FOR XML AUTO, XMLSCHEMA
```

The result in the results is correct, which starts something like:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet3" xmlns:schema="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

With a column header of:

```
XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
```

But in both cases the result is truncated.

So I turned to `sqlcmd` and wrote a PowerShell script:

```
$DB = "TRACE"
$CMDBASE="sqlcmd -d $DB"
$OUTFILE="./output.txt"

iex "$CMDBASE -i schema2_script.sql -o $OUTFILE -u"
```

With the `.._script.sql` being one of the above.

However the results are in hex, output as ASCII. In the case of the `XMLSCHEMA` query, the output in the text file starts as:

```
0x44104E004C00530043006F006E007300690067006E006D0065006
```

With a 'column header' of:

```
XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B
```

How do I get the output to be XML ASCII Text (UTF-* is fine).

The table itself has no Binary columns.

I tried `FOR XML RAW, BINARY BASE64` from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/example-retrieving-binary-data thinking that might help but doesn't (as not dealing with binary data per-se).

`sqlcmd` doesn't mention anything about binary or hex and as you can see, I supplied the `-u` command to output as UTF-8 thinking that might help.  With / without makes no difference.

Does anyone know what i can do to get ASCII(-like) output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions:

1. The first is to the problem of the output in Management Studio being truncted - **click on the results link to see the full results**
2. And specifically for my question, to get a usable (ie. XML) output, use the TYPE directive:

   `select * FROM trNLSConsignment FOR XML RAW, TYPE, XMLSCHEMA`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/type-directive-in-for-xml-queries

Oh, and add a `-y 0` arg to have variable length output (otherwise it truncates).

```
...
iex "$CMDBASE -i schema2_script.sql -o $OUTFILE -u -y 0"
```

OR if you use Powershell's `Invoke-Sqlcmd` with an `Out-File` then add a `-width x` argument with some value for the width of a line.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $DB -MaxCharLength 99999 -query $queryString |
            Out-File -FilePath "$initialOutFile" -width 99999
```